# Cannot use Yast CA management module from command line

Tags: opensuse, openssl, certificates, yast

I am trying to create a new certificate authority using Yast as follows:

```
yast2 ca_mgm createCA caname=democa cn=democa email=peter@gmail.com days=3650 keyLength=2048 keyPasswd=sillypassword
```

But it fails with the following output: `Modifying RequestGenerationData failed.`
And an exit code 16 that according to Yast's man is just a generic client error.

If I do the same using GUI, it succeeds. If then I try to create a certificate in this authority using

```
yast2 ca_mgm createCertificate
```

and other respective options, it fails with the same error.
I am starting `yast2` as a root of course.
Alternatively, I'd like to know if it is possible to create a CA using CLI in a way that is compatible with Yast (so that afterwards it can be used in Yast GUI).

OS version: openSUSE Leap 42.1 (x86_64)

Thanks in advance.